# Use of clock_getres - newbie Linux C

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to determine the granularity of the timers on my Linux box.  According to the man pages for clock_getres, I should be able to use this snippet:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  clockid_t types[] = { CLOCK_REALTIME, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, (clockid_t) - 1 };

  struct timespec spec;
  int i = 0;
  for ( i; types[i] != (clockid_t) - 1; i++ )
  {
    if ( clock_getres( types[i], &spec ) != 0 )
    {
      printf( "Timer %d not supported.\n", types[i] );
    }
    else
    {
      printf( "Timer: %d, Seconds: %ld Nanos: %ld\n", i, spec.tv_sec, spec.tv_nsec );
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to build like so:
    gcc -o timertest timertest.c

This works great on Solaris but on Linux I get the error:

```
/tmp/ccuqfrCK.o: In function `main':
timertest.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `clock_getres'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried passing -lc to gcc, apparently clock_getres is defined in libc, but it makes no difference.  I must be missing something simple here - any ideas?

Thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 15):

You need to link with with RT library (`-lrt`)

Comment: Even on Linux, the manpage for clock_getres states "Link with -lrt."  Russ, you're just lucky that Linux is as forgiving as it is.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, `clock_getres()` POSIX function (optional "realtime" part - note **REALTIME** mark on POSIX page http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock_getres.html) does not report timers granularity in Linux. It can return only two predefined results: either 1/HZ for low resolution clocks (where HZ is value of CONFIG_HZ macro used when configuring linux kernel, typical values are 100 300 1000) or 1 ns for high resolution clocks (hrtimers).

The file `linux/include/linux/hrtimer.h` in kernel has the comment about such granularity and about meaning of `clock_getres()` result
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/hrtimer.h

```
269 /*
270  * The resolution of the clocks. The resolution value is returned in
271  * the clock_getres() system call to give application programmers an
272  * idea of the (in)accuracy of timers. Timer values are rounded up to
273  * this resolution values.
274  */
```

So, even if the timer source is registered as "hrtimer" (high-resolution timer), it may clocks not every nanosecond (ns). And value returned from `clock_getres()` will only say that this timer was not rounded (because `timespec` struct has nanosecond precision).

In Linux the POSIX API is often implemented by glibc (or its derivatives like eglibc), which are linked to the all programs by default (`-lc` option of linker). Glibc with versions less than 2.17 separated some optional parts of POSIX into additional libraries, for example, `-lpthread` or `-lrt`. `clock_getres()` was defined in `-lrt`.

`-lrt` option is not needed for glibc 2.17 and newer, according to Linux man page of `clock_getres()` and `clock_gettime()` functions, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html

> Link with -lrt (only for glibc versions before 2.17).

The change was also registered in the compatibility tracker: http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/compat_reports/glibc/2.16.0_to_2.17/abi_compat_report.html

> Added Symbols  ... libc-2.17.so ... clock_getres